# Can I cross-reference to an external document if path and filename have spaces?

Tags: cross-referencing

PART I: BLANK SPACES IN PATH

I am a tech writer trying to cross-reference to a file in a different folder. Both the folder name and the file name I inherited have one or more spaces. If I change the folder and/or file name, the developers will probably have to change some scripts, so I'm exploring my options before going that route.

(1) In the calling document (the Admin Guide), I added quotation marks around the path name. This avoided error messages on my calling file, but I'm not sure if that is enough to make the cross-reference process work:

```
\usepackage{xr}  % so can reference Install guide from Admin guide
\externaldocument{"../Installation Guide/SMS Install Guide"}
```

(2) Below is the `\ref` in the Admin Guide (calling document) :

```
\chapter{Document History}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Chapter \thechapter: Document History} 
This is a test of referencing the Installation Guide, Section~\ref{InstallCustom}
```

(3) This code is in the Install Guide being referenced:

```
\section{Configure Custom Reports (Optional)}\label{sec:InstallCustom}
Below are instructions for installing and configuring the software necessary for....
```

(4) RESULTS, after compiling the Install Guide twice then the Admin Guide twice:

This is a test of referencing the Installation Guide, Section ??

PART II : COMPILE ORDER

The code above is my test of a direct cross-reference from the Admin Guide to the Install Guide that is in a different folder. However, once that is working I will have one more hop to negotiate. I need to be able to put the call that is in (2) above into a separate document, ssrs.tex, that is pulled into the Admin Guide with an `\include`. What would then be the recommended compile/build order?

Thanks,
Audrey

Comment: when I'm ruler of the world I'm going to ban spaces in filenames. `xr` really just manages `\input` of aux files and as web2c tex can handle spaces in filenames xr could certainly be made to work, it probably just needs to be more careful not to drop spaces. I could check I suppose. note apart from spaces starting a path with `../` ie going up the tree may be banned for security reasons

Comment: if you can: write yourself a script that gathers the relevant .aux files from all your folders, compiles the latex document and then removes the local copies auf the .aux files

Comment: if the label is `\label{sec:InstallCustom}` the ref will have to be `\label{sec:InstallCustom}` not `\ref{InstallCustom}` irrespective of whether `xr` is used.

Comment: a reading paths starting with `../` is baned anyway I'd just copy the `aux` files from `SMS Install Guide` into the local directory  using `"` should work but of not just remove the spaces while copying.

Comment: @Bort can you explain to me the benefit of doing this? tnx.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I successfully used ../ in my initial test. In detail, I am working in a folder named Documentation. Within Documentation are the folders "Administration Guide" and "Install Guide". I created the folder TestFolder (no spaces!), also under Documentation, and put my target with the `/label` in it. That happened to work.

Comment: Do others have experience with, or insights or opinions about using `../` in connection with `\externaldocument` for cross-referencing to other documents? (this question was going to be the second paragraph of my comment to @david, but I just discovered that ENTER=Submit!)  -Audrey

Comment: @AudreyFisher sorry banning `../` is just paranoid setting which by default is for writing not reading, see texmf.cnf which says this (linebreaks will go in comment, easier to read the file) % Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.`
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a

Comment: @AudreyFisher well the benefit for me seemed to be that I would expect that to work. On an academic level it would be nice to have a patch for the package, but on a practial level you only need it to work and this sounds like a minute or two in bash. also if you deal with multiple documents i thought you already have some kind of process going on (say a makefile)

Comment: @Bort, tnx....I'm a writer and not a programmer, so just trying to get my head around it conceptually....seems to me that the script would (1) take care of compiling everything and (2)~bring disparate documents into range for cross-references. Is that accurate enough in layman's terms? Luckily I have a quad (cubicle) mate who is great at scripting and amenable to helping out, who I expect will put together the script you describe.

Comment: Have you actually tried it with a matching `\label` and `\ref`? Because it doesn't matter where things are or whether they have spaces or how great the script is, if you pass something different to `\ref` than you do to `\label` then it ain't gonna work.

Comment: @AudreyFisher Please have a look at the packages zref-xr and grffile, both written by Heiko Oberdieck. Maybe it works out of the box with them. Heiko's developments often have unexpected advantages.

Comment: @AudreyFisher No, my suggestions does not work, grffile provides its machinery only for graphics.

Answer (score 2):

This here seems to work. But as I like David never use spaces in file names I'm not really sure if it won't break somewhere.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xr}  % so can reference Install guide from Admin guide
\makeatletter
\def\XR@[#1]#2{{%
  \makeatletter
  \def\XR@prefix{#1}%
  \XR@next"#2.aux"\relax\\}} %added quotes
\makeatother
\externaldocument{test with space/test}
\externaldocument{test-ansinew}
\begin{document}

blalb \ref{abc}, \ref{blub}, \ref{x}

\end{document}
```